# Ordinal date in section

Tags: errors, datetime

```
\monthname[10] \ordinaldate{10}
```

produces `October 10th`, as expected. But once I put it into a section, I get this error:

```
! Argument of \@ordinalnum has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.11 \section*{\monthname[10] \ordinaldate{10}}
```

What is happening and why?

**EDIT**

Though

```
\section*{\monthname[10] \protect\ordinaldate{10}}
```

works just fine for displaying the date like I want to, I suddenly get a new error from the main file that I am including this `2006-10.tex` file from:

```
! Extra \else.
\@include ...ediate \closeout \@partaux \fi \else 
                                                  \deadcycles \z@ \@nameuse ...
l.89 \include{Years/2006-10}
```

I am not using `\if` or `\else` statements anywhere in either the main document, or this included document. The error goes away if I remove `\protect\ordinaldate{10}`.

Weirdly enough, adding other things like `\protect\dayofweekname{10}{10}{2006}` doesn't produce such an error. Only putting in `\protect\ordinaldate{10}` causes the include error.

**EDIT 2**

`\protect\ordinalnum{10}` doesn't cause such an error, despite `\protect\ordinaldate{10}` doing so, so I guess I will just use `\ordinalnum` for now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to `\protect` `\ordinaldate`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{datetime}
\begin{document}

\section{\monthname[10] \protect\ordinaldate{10}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It worked! Thank you, and I wonder if you could take a stab at the new problem I'm having now?

Comment: @wrongusername you need to `\protect` it only in sectional units (such as in `\section`, `\chapter`...) and maybe also in `\caption`. No need to `\protect` it in other contexts.